# Accessing SMT pins on prototype board

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering, prototyping, modem, module

I need to be able to solder wires to the hidden pins of an smt ic. The ic is soldered directly to the pcb, and they are not visible. I need to access the PCM audio interface on a sim7500e, and the only way to do that would be for me to solder wires to the pcb, then resolder the sim7500e. Does anyone know how to do this? For reference, here is the [prototyping module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/LTE-CAT1-SIM7500E-breakout-board-B1-B3-B7-B8-B20-for-Europe-1pc/32966938826.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.75ac4c4dLYhU0D) I am using.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Do you even have the equipment to desolder it in the first place? Or solder it back?

Comment: This looks like it has a very low probability of success to me. You would probably have more luck just redesigning the module.

Comment: I don't see you being able to do this without a reflow oven/plate setup. The chip is too big for hot air (without some kind of special hood), in all likelihood you are going to end up damaging the chip taking it off, then it will never sit flat trying to get it back on with wires underneath it.

Comment: thanks everyone, I was trying to avoid redesigning the module because the sim7500e is nearly £30 each, so for a hobby it gets pretty steep pretty quickly.

Comment: The sim7500e has an LGA package, which usually means most of the traces are visible and accessible even though the pins themselves are hidden. The exception would be pin-to-pin connections routed under the chip. Is this the case here? If this is PCM _interface_ it has to be interfaced to something else on the PCB, has it not?

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, the pcm interface is not connected to anything, so the pads are there, but no traces to them.